# Using Mobile Emulation via Chrome's remote debugging protocol

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I like the "device mode" mobile emulation from chrome devtools. But I'd like to use it from within a testing environment.

Chrome has a debugging protocol accessible via a port or `chrome.debugger` extension API. Can I enable emulation via that?

Answer (score 2):

First up, Chromedriver offers this as a first-class feature: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation

From the [Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol), you can can use the [`setDeviceMetricsOverride`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/protocol.json&q=file:protocol.json%20setDeviceMetricsOverride&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=366) command to initialize the essential mobile emulation characteristics.

Check out some [projects on GitHub using setDeviceMetricsOverride](https://github.com/search?l=javascript&q=setDeviceMetricsOverride&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) for example code.

Comment: Do you know if the Chromedriver if used in a grid support touch actions? Can't get it to work.